# Find the best match in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have got the following array:

```
let x = [
  { name: "Bad", value: 2 },
  { name: "Critical", value: 1 },
  { name: "High", value: 5 },
  { name: "Medium", value: 5 },
];
```

The expectation is to look for `"Critical"` first, if the array has it, return that, else look for `"High"` then look for `"Medium"` and so on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] if you haven't already (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mre] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: (This doesn't sound like *filtering* to me, it sounds like *finding*.)

Answer (score 3):

You can store the priorities in an array and then loop over the array and for every priority check if there's an object and whenever an object is found, return it. If the entire `priorities` array is exhausted then return `null` (*or whatever you want*).

```js
const arr = [
    { name: "Bad", value: 2 },
    { name: "Critical", value: 1 },
    { name: "High", value: 5 },
    { name: "Medium", value: 5 },
  ],
  priorities = ["Critical", "High", "Medium", "Bad"],
  search = (arr, priorities) => {
    for (let p of priorities) {
      const obj = arr.find(({ name }) => name === p);
      if (obj) {
        return obj;
      }
    }
    return null;
  };

console.log(search(arr, priorities));
```

You can also sort the array based on the priority.

- Create a `Map` that stores the priorities.
- Sort `arr` based on the priorities stored in the map.

```js
const arr = [
    { name: "Bad", value: 2 },
    { name: "Critical", value: 1 },
    { name: "High", value: 5 },
    { name: "Medium", value: 5 },
  ],
  priorities = new Map([
    ["Critical", 4],
    ["High", 3],
    ["Medium", 2],
    ["Bad", 1],
  ]),
  sortedArr = [...arr].sort(
    (a, b) => priorities.get(b.name) - priorities.get(a.name)
  );

console.log(sortedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let value = x.find(x => x.name == "Critical") 
  || x.find(x => x.name == "High")
  || x.find(x => x.name == "Medium") ...
```

Comment: This will loop over the entire array N times where N is the number of potential values for `name`

Comment: But the loop will break on the first occurrence of the priority, with each subsequent find being less likely to be called. And judging by the names there will be no more than 10 entries in that array.

Comment: The loop will break on the first occurrence but if you don't find the value in the first loop, you will be needlessly scanning those elements on the second loop, and so on

Answer (score 0):

First, define the `order` in which you want to look for items, then use that to sort the items in the array. Lastly, `find` based on all the items in your sort `order`. The first match will be returned, since the items are sorted.

```js
const x = [{name: 'Bad',value: 2}, {name: 'High', value: 5}, {name: 'Medium', value: 5}, {name: 'Critical', value: 1}],
      order = ['Critical','High','Medium'],
      //sort according to above order
      output = x.sort(
          ({name:na},{name:nb}) => 
          order.findIndex(v => v === na) - order.findIndex(v => v === nb)
      )
      //Now find items matching name in order
      .find( ({name}) => order.includes(name) );
      
console.log( output );
```

**NOTE**

- Since your data is already sorted in the desired order, I moved the element with `name = "Critical"` to the end of the array.
- If the data will always be sorted according to the priority you want to find the items, then no sorting is needed.